# Why is .htaccess non-www not redirecting to www for subfolders?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I've used cPanel's redirect tool to redirect all non-www requests to www. It's working for the root but not working for sub-folders.

For example: `http://my-domain.com/test` DOES NOT redirect to `http://www.my-domain.com/test`

This is the .htaccess content generated by the cPanel's redirect tool:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.my\-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I can't figure out why this is not working for subfolders. I even added `Options +FollowSymlinks` and `RewriteBase /` to .htaccess file but still not working.

There is something else I couldn't understand. I recently moved to a new web host. In my old host account, I didn't even have redirections set and it was working fine. Can web hosts redirect all non-www requests to www as their *global setting* without having to add .htaccess file in the website's root?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Also, make sure that you don't have it configured to enforce the "www" in cPanel.

Comment: @JonLin No there is nothing else in my .htaccess file that is in the root. In regards to your second comment, where do I check that?

Comment: My guess is probably something like this: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ReDirects

Comment: Try changing the Rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com/$1  [R=301,L]`. All those escapes are not needed. When you say "sub-folders", you mean a simple URI of /test and not a test subdomain? Do you happen to _have_ a test subdomain? If you do, try another folder.

Comment: @PhilPerry Tried your suggestion. Still not working. The subfolders are just ordinary subfolders not subdomain.

Comment: If those three lines are all that's in your .htaccess, it ought to work. That's the code I would give someone to do it manually (just change `.com` to `\.com` in the RewriteCond, as it's a regular expression). Perhaps there's something else that cPanel has done to block it? I wouldn't use cPanel to set up redirections -- always edit .htaccess by hand. If nothing else works, use cPanel to remove this redirection, and then add it back in by hand -- see if that works.

Comment: @JonLin I looked at that doc. I did exactly how the doc suggested. I chose `Permanent Redirection` as the redirection type. Chose `Do Not Redirect www.` option and ticked the `Wild Card Redirect` box. I think the process I followed initially was correct.

Comment: @PhilPerry I just tried removing the cPanel redirection and added .htaccess by hand. Still no luck. I think I will have to talk to the host and let them figure it out.

Comment: @PhilPerry About the subfolders, they are folders where other websites are installed. Does that make it just an ordinary subfolder?

Comment: So, test.my-domain.com would actually go to a separate website? That sounds like they're actually subdomains then, and that could be messing up your attempt to redirect non-www to www (just for folders which happen to be subdomain roots). You wouldn't want to add www to a subdomain anyway (usually doesn't _hurt_, but it looks stupid).

Comment: @PhilPerry There is a website installed at `my-domain.com/test` but it's not set up as a subdomain. So test.my-domain.com currently does not exist.

Comment: If it's not a subdomain, and even manually adding a redirect doesn't work, you'll have to call in your host's tech support to see what's going on.